# R taking up too much memory when looping to create list of data frames

Tags: r, memory

So the idea is to loop through a dataset with 50 million rows and read a million observations each iteration, then take a random sample of 1% from the 1 million rows, and put the sample in a list. In the end this should give around 500k rows, or 1% of 50 million rows. Unfortunately, R is consuming way too much memory as the iterations grow. Am I using the rm() and gc() functions incorrectly to remove the objects? I can't tell where the memory is being used.

```
library(data.table)

set.seed(123)
iter <- seq(1000000, 47000000, 1000000)
j <- 1
for(i in iter)
{ 
train <- read.csv(file='train.csv', nrows = 1000000, skip=i, 
header=FALSE) 

smp_size <- floor(.01 * nrow(train)) 
train_ind <- sample(seq_len(nrow(train)), size = smp_size)
train <- train[train_ind, ]

datalist[[j]] <- train
j <- j+1

rm(train)
rm(train_ind)
rm(smp_size)
gc()
}

newtrain <- rbindlist(datalist)
```

Comment: How much memory is being used, and is it possible that the performance lag you are seeing is actually just due to `datalist` getting filled with 500k rows?  How much space does one row take roughly?

Comment: 1 million rows would take maybe a few hundred mbs or so. The entire 50million size dataset ifs 6GB. Meanwhile R seems to be climbing to the 2GBs over the iterations where it should be simply putting 500k worth of observations as a list of dataframes. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Why don't you use `fread` (which is much faster than `read.csv`) and work with data.tables? You should not need to call `gc` manually. Consider getting more RAM to be able to read such datasets in one step.

Comment: Data tables could definitely give me better luck, but I'm still curious why this method doesn't work.

Comment: Maybe not directly related, but that use of `read.csv` is quite inefficient. Open a connection to the file: `con<-file("train.csv",open="rt")` and then just call `read.csv(con,nrows = 1000000,header=FALSE)`. The reading automatically starts from where it ended last iteration, instead of reading again from the start and skipping rows.

Comment: @nicola I have a reading comprehension problem.  Comment deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The performance lag you are seeing as your script and for loop progress is most likely due to the overhead of your list `datalist` as it grows to roughly 50 million rows.

Here is your call to `read.csv`:

```
train <- read.csv(file='train.csv', nrows = 1000000, skip=i, header=FALSE)
```

It appears that you are reading one million rows at a time, up to about 50 million rows.  In your comment you mentioned:

> "1 million rows would take maybe 100 mbs or so"

Then 50 million rows should take about 5GB, which is exactly in line with what you are observing.

As an aside, running `gc()` *should* remove the `train`, `train_ind`, and `smp_size` variables from your workspace.  However, this is a moot point because they are clobbered (overwritten) in each subsequent iteration of the for loop.  In other words, garbage collecting these variables won't really improve your performance because they are scoped to the for loop, which will be garbage collected anyway after each iteration.

Comment: The datalist should grow to 500k rows, not 50 million. I wanted the train data.frame to basically be overwritten each iteration essentially. I feel like I am missing something but it's late at night. I'll look over when I wake up.

Comment: I think your script has a problem.  It appears you are reading in millions of rows _and_ storing them.

Comment: Solved it. The OS was not freeing up the memory allocated to the R session.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem. It seems to be that the code is perfectly well and good but the OS was not releasing the memory R clears up, whether through gc() or once the objects go out of scope. This is an issue that has been discussed on this website but very infrequently and vaguely. Indeed, it is hard to find much info about this issue the internet.

Switching from Windows XP to Windows 7 and then finally to Linux solved the problem. Mallinfo also can be used with Linux to request the OS to relse the memory it has allocated to R.

Comment: What was being freed which was causing the problem?  Did you also increase your RAM when you changed the OS?

Comment: It seems there were two issues. 1. I was reading 50 million rows because of the skip argument. Using a connection solved this. 2. I was having problems using gc() because the OS wasn't releasing the memory.